# Need help getting tutorial working: Using urdf with robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-fuerte, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [Using urdf with robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) tutorial, it says:

> Run rviz, choosing odom as your fixed frame. Add a Robot Model and TF.

and I got stuck there.  I ran:

> rosrun rviz rviz

but not sure how to do any of the other steps mentioned above. Anyone know how to make this work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54837/need-help-getting-tutorial-working:-using-urdf-with-robot_state_publisher/) by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In RViz, choose "Add Display" and and add a TF and RobotModel display. Where it says "Global Options", set the fixed frame to "odom".

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on 2013-02-10**:
That worked!  Thanks.

**Comment by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on 2013-02-10**:
I updated the wiki page to make it a bit clearer.